# Template Driven form Cannot read property 'required' of null-Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-forms

Am working on angular 6 with template driven form.Face some issue on validation

html code

```
             <div class="form-group">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="name"
                                required [(ngModel)]="configuration.name" #name="ngModel"
                                minlength="2">
                            <span *ngIf="submitted && name.errors['required']" class="text-danger">Please
                                Enter Name</span>


                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)=" sav(form)">Save</button>
    </div>
    </form>
```

when i click on save button without any input its showing validation message,after that i type some values in that input text field it showing an error

am also tried name.errors.required and  name.errors?.required both are failed

[image]

Comment: try `name.invalid` in place of `name.errors['required']`

Comment: can i check minlength like this name.errors['minlength'] or is thr any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

You can you the below code for minlength and required field validations

```
  <span *ngIf="submitted && name.errors.required" class="text-danger">Please
                            Enter Name</span>
  <span *ngIf="submitted && name.errors.minlength" class="text-danger">Please
                            Enter 2 characters</span>
```

Comment: tried showing an error- Identifier 'minlength' is not defined. '__type' does not contain such a member